# Minor comment indentation glitch (on SO)

Tags: bug, comments

I've noticed this a few times, never seen quite what causes it: A comment on a question can be markedly more indented than normal (on Chrome). I've taken a screenshot and drawn a vertical blue line from comments on the first answer up to the comment on the question that's indented, and highlighted the gap in red:

[image]

I had flagged the comment as obsolete (since it's replying to a now-deleted comment), if that's relevant.

FWIW, here's the current state of that comment's row in the DOM:

```
<tr id="comment-58065986" class="comment ">
    <td>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class=" comment-score">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="comment-flag flag-on comment-flag-indicator" title="You have already flagged this comment">flag</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td class="comment-text">
        <div style="display: block;" class="comment-body">
            <span class="comment-copy">@ShrikanthBuds, why?</span> –&nbsp;
            <a href="/users/487524/epoch" title="9557 reputation" class="comment-user">epoch</a>
            <span class="comment-date" dir="ltr"><a class="comment-link" href="#comment58065986_35174255"><span title="2016-02-03 10:25:16Z" class="relativetime-clean">10 mins ago</span></a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I'd link to the question, but the comment has already been deleted.

This is on Stack Overflow.